# wifi on Dell XPS 9560 is unstable and drops frequently

Tags: wireless

My Dell XPS 9560 has some spotty wifi connection issues. Either the connection drops frequently or very slow.

Tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205?noredirect=1#comment1780906_425205)

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info &&
  chmod +x wireless-info &&
  ./wireless-info
```

[Here are my pastebin contents](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BpF4bs96gm/)
But no improvements - what could be the issue? When i boot into Windows 10 - the same wifi adator works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my many years of experience with wireless issues involving several different Linux distributions, I never saw scan results with 107 (!!) visible access points!

In the interest of security and privacy, the wireless script that you ran redacts the MAC addresses in every instance. You are connected to ‘nmguest’, redacted as AC1. AC1 has a signal strength of 63/100. There are other instances of nmguest that are evidently physically closer because they have a higher signal strength; for example, the instance redacted as AC45 has a signal strength of 74/100.

I suggest that you run:

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

Make a note of the MAC address of the instance with the highest signal strength and  use Network Manager to bind to it like this:

[image]

The MAC address should be entered in the BSSID space in Network Manager. That should bind to the strongest instance of nmguest as well as prevent dropping as the wireless searches for a better connection from among several instances with the same name.

Save and close Network Manager. Tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: How to access/start network-manager on Ubuntu Linux 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Click the wifi symbol at the upper right. Click the name of the network to which you are connected, presumably nmguest. Select Wifi Settings. Next to your network, click the gear symbol. Select the Identity tab and, add theMAC address under BSSID. Apply and close. https://youtu.be/Z5DwRRP_whk

Comment: thanks for the help. But what exactly this does? I am connecting my personal laptop to the Guest wifi at work.

Comment: It binds the wireless to the *strongest* instance of nmguest, stopping it from dropping as it roams to weaker instances.